# silverlight Custom splash screen with animation

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend, splash-screen

I have checked out a few samples for customizing the splash screen in silverlight which runs before the SL app loads and got it to work as well.

While the standard progress bar is fine and works well, I was wondering what else can I do with it. I want to create some animation using blend, using only the core basic Silverlight controls like the rectangle itself that is used for the custom progress bar.

Is there a way to create the animation in blend where I create a state for the rectangle where I get it to glow and call the go to state property from the javascript file?

Has anyone done something like this?

Even if I dont use states. Suppose if I just want to spin the rectangle on its axis and get it to glow on and off as it spins. How does one achieve that?.. or this too much to ask of a custom splash screen?